# Linearization of if-then constraint

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, linearization

I'm trying to linearize a constraint of this form:
if a == b then c = 1
where a and b are positive integers and c is a binary variable.
I'm looking for a solution like this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792360/how-to-linearize-if-then-constraint
which doesn't work in this case.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: `c = 1 if a==b else 0`? Or even simpler, `c = int(a==b)`

Comment: @not_speshal cannot do that. I'm plugging the constraint onto Pyomo and I need a precise mathematical linear formulation

Comment: It wasn't clear to me why that other solution wouldn't work in your case.  Can you explain why not?  Did you try it, or does it just seem wrong because it is framed the other way around?

Comment: @TMBailey Pyomo requires constraint expressions to return unnested expression objects. Returning an expression with a nested expression (a==b) fails to compile. Besides, the if commonly used in programming doesn't qualify as a linear expression... try to see it as a sort of step function, where you have a certain x threshold where the y value changes, it is clearly nonlinear.

Comment: @Unziello you should include that comment in your question. It's much more helpful to know _why_ it doesn't work in this case. Include all relevant information in your question, since people might miss information given in a comment

Answer (score 3):

The implication

```
 a = b => c = 1

 (a,b: integer variables, c: a binary variable)
```

can be re-stated as:

```
 c = 0 => a >= b + 1 
          or
          a <= b - 1
```

(Using that a,b are integers). An "or" needs an extra binary variable. So we can write:

```
 a >= b + 1 - M δ - M c
 a <= b - 1 + M (1-δ) + M c
 δ ∈ {0,1}
```

Here `M` is a large enough constant (to be chosen with care).

Comment: Nice.  `pyomo` seems to want the variables in constraints to all appear on the same side of the inequality, but that's easily done.

Comment: No, Pyomo does not require that.